# Searching a String into Vec<String> in rust

Tags: rust, binary-search

I'm writing a program that interprets a language.

I need to search for a string (not known at compile time) in a `Vec`.

```rust
fn get_name_index(name: &String, array: &Vec<String>) -> usize {
    match array.binary_search(name) {
        Ok(index) => index,
        Err(_) => {
            eprintln!("Error : variable {:?} not found in name array", name);
            std::process::exit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

This happens multiple times during execution, but at the moment, the `array.binary_search()` function does not return the right answer.

I searched for the error, but my array is what it should be (printing each element, or examining with gdb: the same), and the error is still there.

Is there any other way to search for a `String` in a `Vec<String>`? Or is there an error in my code?

Thanks

Comment: `binary_search` requires the array to be sorted. `['_res', 'b', 'a']` is not sorted.

Comment: Some things to note about being idiomatic are to take in `&str` instead of `&String` and `&[String]` instead of `&Vec<String>`. Also, using `std::process::exit` is very unidiomatic rust, try using a `Result` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But if my `&String` is not known at compile time, is it possible to convert it to `&str` ? If so, I don't understand well the difference between them. And for `std::process::exit`, I had already planed to change my code to use `Result` in case of error, but as it is very recursive this require lots of change...

Comment: A `str` is the data in a string, its size is not known at compile time due to the nature of the data. A `String` is essentially a manageable `str` where you can grow it and mutate the contents. Anywhere you want a `&str` you can pass a `&String` or you can do `&*my_string`. Using a result in a recursive function is easy; `fn my_fn() -> Result<...> { my_fn()?; Ok(...) }`. The `?` operator tries to unwrap an option or result, if it can't then it returns early with an `Err` or a `None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a few issues: data must be sorted before using a binary search. A binary search is a fast search algorithm (`O(log n)`, or scales as the log of the size of the container), much faster than a linear search (`O(n)`, or scales linear to the size of the container). However, any speed improvements from a binary search are dwarfed by the overhead of sorting the container (`O(n log n)`).

## Single Search

Therefore, the best approach depends on how often you search your container. If you are only going to check it a few times, you should use a linear search, as follows:

```
fn get_name_index(name: &String, array: &Vec<String>) -> Option<usize> {
    array.iter().position(|&&x| x == name)
}
```

## Repeated Searches

If you are going to repeatedly call `get_name_index`, you should use a binary search (or possibly even better, below):

```
// Sort the array before using
array.sort_unstable();

// Repeatedly call this function
fn get_name_index(name: &String, array: &Vec<String>) -> Option<usize> {
    match array.binary_search(name) {
        Ok(index) => Some(index),
        Err(_)    => None,
    }
}
```

However, this may be suboptimal for some cases. A few considerations: a [HashSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) may be faster for certain sets of data (`O(1)` complexity at its best). However, this is slightly misleading, since all the characters of the name must be processed on each compare for a `HashSet`, while generally only a few characters must be compared to determine whether to jump left or right for a binary search. For data that is highly uniform and mostly differs with a few characters at the end, a `HashSet` might be better, otherwise, I'd generally recommend using `binary_search` on the vector.

Answer (score 1):

As mcarton said, the vector needs to be sorted before you can do a binary search. Here's an example:

```
let mut v = vec![String::from("_res"), String::from("b"), String::from("a")];
println!("{:?}", &v);

v.sort_unstable();
println!("{:?}", &v);
```

I tried this with your code and it found "a" in the second position. Without the call to `sort_unstable()` it failed to find "a".

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to sort the data (`O(nlogn)` performance) to use a binary search (`O(logn)` performance) to avoid using a standard search (`O(n)` performance), unless you're searching numerous times.

Comment: Okayyy, now I understand ! Thank you, but if, as said @AlexanderHuszagh, it doesn't make sense to use binary_search(), how can I do a standard search ? Rust doc is not expensive in explainations...

Comment: @aunetx, you can use the Iterator [find](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) or [position](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position) methods, both which use a linear search to find an element by a custom predicate. In this case, you want a simple equality predicate.

Comment: @David, I would recommend updating your answer to include both algorithms: one for repeated searches within the same list (sort then use a binary search, although you may want to use a set in that case), or a simple linear search using `find()` or `position`.